# Conditionally reset row counter with Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I've seen lots of questions that are similar to the above, but not one that matches exactly what I am trying to do.

Which is

```
row_rk    time_sk   date         lagged_date    mycounter
1         1         '31-01-17'   '31-01-17'     1
1         2         '31-01-17'   '31-01-17'     1
1         3         '31-01-17'   '31-01-17'     1
1         4         '28-02-17'   '31-01-17'     2
1         5         '28-02-17'   '28-02-17'     2
1         6         '28-02-17'   '28-02-17'     2
1         7         '31-03-17'   '28-02-17'     3
1         8         '31-03-17'   '31-01-17'     3
1         9         '31-03-17'   '31-01-17'     3
```

The closest I have got is using:

```
select 
a.*,
row_number()

over (

partition by row_rk, lagged_date

order by time_sk asc 
 reset when date <> lagged_date
)                                                       as mycounter 
from mytable a
;
```

That is giving me a value which is incrementing the row number with each line of data, then resetting it when the row_rk and lagged date combination change. So looking as so:

```
row_rk    time_sk   date         lagged_date    mycounter
    1         1         '31-01-17'   '31-01-17'     1
    1         2         '31-01-17'   '31-01-17'     2
    1         3         '31-01-17'   '31-01-17'     3
    1         4         '28-02-17'   '31-01-17'     1
    1         5         '28-02-17'   '28-02-17'     2
    1         6         '28-02-17'   '28-02-17'     3
    1         7         '31-03-17'   '28-02-17'     1
    1         8         '31-03-17'   '31-01-17'     2
    1         9         '31-03-17'   '31-01-17'     3
```

Can anyone please provide a solution?

Thanks

Comment: You didin't explain the rules how to get this result, but it looks like a `DENSE_RANK()
over (
partition by row_rk
order by date)`

Comment: thanks for replying. that did exactly what i was looking for. i've literally never heard of dense_rank() before though. is there a list within the teradata documentation of functions of this type? that would be a useful read for me...

Comment: It's not unique to Teradata. It's part of the ANSI SQL:2011 standard. I think you are looking for this: https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1145-160K/bff1472241107355.html

Comment: You can download the Functions & Operators manual matching your Teradata release from here: https://www.info.teradata.com/doclist.cfm?txtTitle=&txtProdID=B035-1145